# How to solve multiple browser and calculators pop ups in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, browser

I use Windows 8.1. Everything was going right for nearly a year. But in the last few months when I open my PC multiple browser windows (default set browser Mojila) and calculator and My Computer (the place where all memory drive resides) windows pop up. It slows  my PC and ultimately hangs it. What to do? It's getting severe... excuse my non-IT language.

Comment: If it hangs every time, chances are that Windows is just re-opening the applications that were open the last time it did not hang?

Comment: If you use [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and look under the "Login" tab (when it is ready), are there multiple entries for "Explorer" and/or "Calc"? If so, you can untick them and restart your computer to see if it has helped. Please report back here and let us know either way.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like the behavior or a worm or virus.  Typically, worms or viruses will create scripts to open a website or other explorer windows on your computer.  Do you have an antivirus installed?  If not, try first running Windows Defender on your computer and see if it can find the virus.  If not, then try [Avast](https://www.avast.com/en-us/index), which is free with registration.

Comment: If that fails I would try running MBAM or re-installing windows.